# sending multiple values from django dropdown

Tags: django

I have a django form with a dropdown menu

```
<form action="/dir/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      <tr><td>
        <select name="listxblocks">
          {% for scname, desc in scenarios %}
          <!--<option value="{% url "workbench_show_scenario" scname %}">{{desc}}/{{scname}}</option>-->
          <option value="{{scname}}">{{desc}}/{{scname}}</option>

          {% endfor %}

        </select>

        </td>
    <td></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

I'm currently passing one value **scname** when submitting the form, I need to pass two values **scname** and **desc** and access them later

How can I send these two values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i need to unpack two values i write both with a known separator:

```
<option name value="{{desc}}#{{scname}}">{{desc}}/{{scname}}</option>
```

then in your views:

```
foo = request.POST.get('listxblocks').split('#')
desc = foo[0]
scname = foo[1]
```

Comment: If any time you got a `#` in `desc` or `scname`, you'll get incorrect values.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully it will work. You can pass a `JSON` string from `option` and convert `json string` to `json object` inside django view

```
<option value="{'desc': {{desc}}, 'scname': {{scname}} }">{{desc}}/{{scname}}</option>
```

and then inside your Django view function

```
import json
blocks = json.loads(request.POST.get('listxblocks'))
desc = blocks['desc']
scname = blocks['scname']
```

Comment: This is helpful with a comment: json should be in a valid format: `<option value='{"desc": "{{desc}}", "scname": "{{scname}}" }'>{{desc}}/{{scname}}</option>` and blocks should be: `blocks = json.loads(request.POST.get('option'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use json arrays if you need a simpler form:

```
<option value='[ "{{desc}}", "{{scname}}" ]'>{{desc}}/{{scname}}</option>
```

This will be serialized into a list in Python:

```
my_list = json.loads(request.POST.get('option'))
print(my_list[0])
print(my_list[1])
```